# Is there any research on wolf and bobcat interactions?

Tags: zoology, ecology, mammals, community-ecology

I'm studying interactions between North American predators, specifically wolves, coyotes and bobcats.

There's evidence from data I've collected from game cameras that suggests a significant interaction between wolves and bobcats. However, I haven't found published literature or reports on interactions between these two carnivores besides a paper by Stenlund (1955) that suggests bobcats may benefit from scavenging wolf kills.

Does anyone know of any publications in peer-reviewed literature, government reports or even reliable observations from biologists in the field on interactions between wolves and bobcats?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Sweden, no clear evidence have been found for interactions between wolf and European bobcat (*Lynx lynx*), see [Wikenros et al, 2010](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/Z09-143#.Wpackuco9aQ). There, they have studied effects of wolfs on the survival of Lynx kittens, spatial movement of Lynx and Lynx' homerange size. The study finds no significant difference in any factor with/without wolves. They also speculate that the reason for a lack of interactions is that the two species use quite different main food resources (at least in Scadinavia); Lynx being specialized on Roe deer and wolves having wider preferences, but mostly Moose.

You should also look at the report *Meta-analysis  on  the  effect  of  competition  between  lynx  and wolf on their diets* ([Lelieveld, 2013](https://www.wolveninnederland.nl/sites/default/files/lit-research-report-2013-03-18-revised.pdf) which might provide more information. From reading the abstract, the report indicates no effects on wolves but that Lynxs might change their foraging behavior.